# Different Layers in a Stack Design

Tags: objective-c, xib

Hello I need help with so called stack design, where you have different layers on top of each other in a XIB-document in Xcode.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear what you are asking and how the answer below solves your problem. Maybe you should first read the "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Answer (score -1):

If you put this under `viewDidLoad` it should work!

```
// Get the path


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"highscore.save"];

// Create a dictionary to hold objects
NSMutableDictionary* myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// Read objects back into dictionary
myDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
NSString *nssHighscore = [myDict objectForKey:@"Highscore"];
highscore = [nssHighscore intValue];


gameState = kStateMenu;
ballVelocity = CGPointMake(0, 0);
gravity = CGPointMake(0, kGravity);
controlType = kTouch;
```